# How do I suppress iTunes internet connection alerts when listening with Wi-Fi disabled?

Tags: itunes, wifi

I will sometimes use iTunes to listen to my laptop's music library while on an airplane or somewhere else I don't have an internet connection, and thus I turn off Wi-Fi to save battery. I haven't had problems with it in the past, but I took several flights today and encountered an annoying alert that came up every time a new track started playing, letting me know that `iTunes could not connect to the iTunes Store. The network is down or unavailable`.

[image: Screenshot of alert]

Well, of course the network is unavailable, I turned it off!

- None of my library was purchased from the iTunes store; my entire library is unencrypted mp3 files on my local drive (mostly purchased from Amazon).

  - These same files are all synced to my iPhone and play just fine on there in Airplane mode.
- The files play as normal, but the above alert comes up every time a new track starts, and bounces the iTunes icon in the dock as well.
- If I start iTunes with an internet connection and then turn the Wi-Fi off, I don't get the alert on every track. However, if I Quit iTunes and start it again with Wi-Fi disabled, I get the alert.
- My last flight was in December and it didn't happen then, but I have automatic updates on and I suspect something may have changed in an update. I'm currently on macOS 10.12.2 and iTunes 12.5.4.42.

Is there any way to allow me to use iTunes with Wi-Fi turned off that doesn't give me the above alert every time a new track starts?

Comment: Have you tried to using Restrictions to disable access to the iTunes store?  I haven't tried it myself so I didn't want to add this as an answer yet.

Comment: Try signing out from the Store in the Accounts menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of the above appear to get rid of the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Today I chatted with Apple Support who told me this is now expected behaviour, that iTunes looks for a connection. Not great.

I have recently moved to El Capitan and use iTunes 12.5.4, I too get this message even when I am offline.

Comment: I have found another entry on this popup problem that discusses workarounds but, in this scenario (iTunes 12.5.4/El Capitan) it remains. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265428/how-to-remove-the-could-not-connect-to-the-itunes-store-error-message-when-you/265925#265925