# Dozens of "iTunes could not connect to iTunes Store. ..."

Tags: macos, itunes

When I play my playlists with iTunes on Mac OS when offline, I get a lot of messages

> *iTunes could not connect to iTunes Store. The network is down or unavailable.*

When I start to play music for my sleep, the next morning I see these error messages:

[image]

It is quite irritating! Why this silly app always wants some connection... I tried to search this using Google, but nothing at all about this specific problem.

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Is known bug in the latest version of iTunes. This might help you https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7790494

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265428/how-to-remove-the-could-not-connect-to-the-itunes-store-error-message-when-you